# What's the C++ version of scanf?

Tags: c++, formatted-input

For example...

```
char* foo;
scanf("%[^\n\r]", foo);
```

How can I do this in C++, without including C libraries?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to what you have posted [aside from the fact that `char *foo` without an allocation of memory, probably will lead to writing to either NULL or some random location in memory] would be

```
 std::string foo;
 std::getline(std::cin, foo);
```

But for more complex cases, where you read multiple items, either `cin >> x >> y >> z;` or `std::getline(std::cin, str); std::stringstream ss(str); ss >> x >> y >> z;` - or some combination thereof.

But C-code that is valid is valid in C++ too. It's not always the "right" solution, but certainly not completely wrong either.

Comment: When parsing input using a `std::stringstream`, you should use `std::istreamstream` instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt: C++98, the same version that standardized the STL.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `std::istringstream` is a typedef for `std::basic_istringstream<char>`.  See C++98 (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) §27.7.2, "Template class basic_istreamstream".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81051/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: @Remy: I've just been dropping hints about the typo in your first comment.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would have appreciated it if you had just said so up front and not wasted my time looking up the references for you.  Oh well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Classic Ben.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ version of `scanf` is [`std::scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and can be found in the `<cstdio>` header. Yes, it's the same function - because C functions can also be used in C++.

Comment: Yes and printf also can be used in C++...but nobody uses it. I'm just asking if there's another way to do this --'...without using c libraries.

Comment: You are probably going to end up [even if you don't do it yourself] include some "c" libraries whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple methods to replace `scanf`.

1. `std::cin` which can be found in the standard library.
2. `std::getline(std::cin, line);` which takes user's input, up to but not including the line break, into a `std::string` variable `line`.